# Add Image Link alt Text through CSS

Tags: html, css

Can I add ALT text of an image link from CSS ?
Below is the CSS I am using for getting the URL of the Image.

```
.reset {
    background-image: url(../images/icon_new_reset.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more on what you are trying to accomplish? Links do not have an "alt" attribute like images do. Do you want an icon next to the link?

Comment: Do you mean that you have an element in class `reset` and you create its visual appearance by setting a background image for it, rather via its content? And would you then want to set an alternative text for situations where the image is not displayed? It cannot be done in CSS, but if you explain what you are trying to accomplish, then there is probably some solution to the original problem. Why don’t you use a content image instead of a background image?

Answer (score 7):

*can I add ALT text of an image link from CSS ?* : **No**

`alt` is attribute of `img` html element. it's not for the css.

You can add it from markup only.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="This is alt text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an image (the HTML `img` element) part of the content. This is a background image added via CSS, for decorative purpose.

If you need to add a meaningful text to a background image, then it shouldn't (more like mustn't) be a background image but a plain (HTML) image.
What if you display your page with CSS desactivated? You won't see the whole content.
What if you desactivate images? Again you won't see the whole content as there is no alt.